# How to load correctly my class?

Tags: objective-c, class, initialization, nsobject

I have a class defined in a an external pair of files, let's name them *engine.h* and *engine.m* . Also, it was given to me the file "engineListener.h".
this is how they look:

**File engine.h:**

```
@interface coreEngine: NSObject {
   NSString *displaydValue;
   id <coreEngineListener> listener;
}
-(coreEngine*)initWithListener:(id <coreEngineListener>) _listener;
//...
```

File **engine.m**

```
//imports here
@interface coreEngine()
-(Boolean) MyOperation: ... ... (etc)
@end
```

File **engineListener.h**

```
//imports here...
@class coreEngine;
@protocol coreEngineListener <NSObject>
@required
-(void) someVariable:(coreEngine *)source;
@end
```

---

Now, in my **myController.h** I have this:

```
//... imports and include ...
@interface myController : NSObject
{
    coreEngine *PhysicsEngine;
}

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;
```

And in the **myController.m** this is what I have:

```
-(id) init
{
    NSAutorelease *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    coreEngine *PhysicsEngine = [[coreEngine alloc] init];

    [PhysicsEngine release];
    [pool drain];
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender
{
    [PhysicsEngine MyOperation:Something];
}
```

The thing now is: the code compiles correctly, but the "[PhysicsEngine MyOperation:Something]" is doing nothing. I'm sure I'm instantiating my class wrongly. The NSObject defined in "engine.h engine.m and enginelistener.h" that I have to load was not made by me, and I have no means to modify it.

I've tried doing some dummy/random things based on what I've seen around on the internet, without knowing 100% what I was doing. I'm not even close to be familiar with ObjectiveC or C/C++, so be gentle with me. I'm totally noob on this subject.
I'm using Xcode 4, and I have also access to XCode 3.2.6

How should I load my class properly?
Any advice is welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class's `-init` should look something like this:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        coreEngine = [[PhysicsEngine alloc] initWithListener:self];    // I assume you don't have a property declared
    }

    return self;
}
```

This follows a standard design pattern for initializing classes. You actually do the initialization by calling `-init` on `super`. Afterwards, if `self` was initialized properly (as it almost always will be), you create your `PhysicsEngine` object. Note that your class needs to conform to the `PhysicsEngineListener` protocol and implement `-someVariable:`.

```
// Declares protocol conformance

@interface MyController : NSObject <PhysicsEngineListener>

// In MyController.m

- (void)someVariable:(PhysicsEngine *)source
{
    // Do whatever this is supposed to do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your interface should have:

```
PhysicsEngine *coreEngine;
```

and MyController.m init:

```
PhysicsEngine *coreEngine = [[PhysicsEngine allow] init];
```

I would be surprised if your code would compile at all.

Also, the convention is that classes are capitalised, and variables are not.  There are probably more things to comment on, but you should start with that.

Comment: I think he re-typed or pasted it wrong. I believe he did mean `PhysicsEngine *coreEngine`.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to know where to start.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, Paul. I changed the original variable names in the post, and I switched, by my error, PhysicsEngine by coreEngine. I hope that now the code starts to make some sense. Im posting this from a Windows computer and im looking at 3 screens. Im sorry.